# Binary file for upload

Tags: iphone

I read [itunesconnect guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) for upload app on appStore and follow steps 
in the last step says you should run Application Loader and select your binary file(zip file) to upload

how can i make this zip file?

does it mean compress my app target file(.app file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right-click (or control-click) on the name in Finder. The fourth item is "Compress ...".
Select that, and you get the zip file they want.

Answer (score 2):

Goto
build/distribution-iphoneos/ inside that you have .app file compress it and that compressed file(.app.zip) is to be uploaded.

upload should be done through APPLICATION LOADER.